# "1: A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks" - Do not treat as error?

Tags: quickbooks

I'm doing a QuickBooks Web Connector integration where I'm querying for all Bill records modified in the last 24 hours in QuickBooks. I'm getting the error above if none are found, but I'd like Web Connector to continue processing the queue of additional (unrelated) requests for this company file, even when no Bills are found. Is it possible to instruct Web Connector to ignore this error? I tried using `<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">` in my request, but this didn't have the desired effect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to instruct Web Connector to ignore this error?

Yes.

> I tried using

That won't work, because that tells *QuickBooks* to ignore errors, not the Web Connector.

You need to look at this method:

> receiveResponseXML

Here's some info:

> integer receiveResponseXML(string ticket, string response, string
>   hresult, string message)
>
> The Web Connector will now pass you a qbXML response to the last qbXML
>   request that was issued.
>
> You should do whatever necessary with the qbXML response, and then
>   return an integer indicating the progress made so far during this
>   session.
>
> If an error has occurred within the SOAP server, return a -1. The Web
>   Connector will next call connectionError().
>
> If there are no more items in the queue, return a 100 (100% finished).
>   The Web Connector will next call closeConnection().
>
> If there are more items in the queue, you can return any number 0 to
>   99 inclusive which indicates the percentage done this session is
>   (returning 65 indicates 65% done, etc.). The Web Connector will next
>   call sendRequestXML(), so that you can send the next request for the
>   next item in the queue.

From:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#integer_receiveresponsexml_string_ticket_string_response_string_hresult_string_message

You can read more in the 100 page PDF documentation Intuit includes in the QuickBooks SDK.

Change your web service so you're returning a positive integer, and the Web Connector will continue without stopping.

If you need more help, post your code.

Comment: Thanks, Keith - this did the job! I was basing my integration off the CodeIgniter example from quickbooks-php (https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_codeigniter_web_connector/controllers/quickbooks.php#L208), and I didn't notice that returning `true` from the error handler allows the requests to continue. (I do see it now in the OOP example https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_oop.php#L235) Thanks for all your help!